# How can I customize the label of an ion-select in Ionic 7?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic7

I am using Ionic 7 and Angular (material) 14.

I want to display a required field indicator (*) in the field labels where applicable.

In Ionic 6, I achieved this by using adding span tag in the ion-label, with a class for styling, ex:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label position="fixed">Title<span class="required-field-indicator">*</span></ion-label>
  <ion-select formControlName="title">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let title of titles" value="{{title}}">{{title}}</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

I could then change the styling of my indicator using CSS:

```
.required-field-indicator {
  color: var(--ion-color-tertiary);
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

My field would display as follows:

[image]

I've now upgraded to Ionic 7, and as per the documentation (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select), the ion-label no longer works with ion-input and ion-select. Instead, one should use the label and label-placement properties on the ion-select component as per example:

[image]

I've updated my code accordingly:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-select label="Title" labelPlacement="fixed" formControlName="title" [required]="true">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let title of titles" value="{{title}}">{{title}}</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

However, with this change, I can no longer add (unless I add it as character in the label property) or customize my required field indicator symbol.

[image]

How can I add a my indicator and style it in Ionic 7?

I have managed to do it using CSS on the ion-input component:

```
.required-indicator {
  .label-text::after {
    content: '*';
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    color: var(--ion-color-tertiary) !important;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding: 2px;
  }
}

<ion-input label="First Name" labelPlacement="fixed" type="text" formControlName="firstName"
              class="required-indicator" [required]="true"></ion-input>
```

But this does not work on the ion-select. I have also tried using the shadow parts and creating a directive to append the indicator the DOM, but I can't access the label in any case. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [CSS Shadow Parts​](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#css-shadow-parts) of the select component.

```html
<ion-select class="required-field-indicator" ...
```

```css
ion-select.required-field-indicator::part(label) {
    /* your style here */
}
```

Comment: The Shadow DOM part `text` refers to the selected option value, or the  `selectedText`-property of the  `ion-select` – not the label.

Comment: You need to use ::part(label), here's the docs, https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#css-shadow-parts

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to accomplish the same thing and finally have come with a solution.

Since the label is in the **shadow-root** of the *IonSelect*, and there's no *part* attribute to expose it, there's no way to style it in the SCSS files **but** it can be done in typescript like this:

```
// For referencing all of the ion-select inside the form
@ViewChildren(IonSelect) ionSelects; 

ngAfterViewInit() {
   // This was for being sure of having all the ion-select loaded
   this.ionSelects.changes.subscribe(data => {
      // Creating the CSS rules we're gonna apply inside the shadow-root
      const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
      sheet.replaceSync(`.label-text::after {
         content: ' *';
         transform: translate(-100%, 0);
         color: var(--ion-color-secondary) !important;
         display: var(--ion-label-display); // This is necessary to show 
         // and hide the asterisk
         font-weight: bolder;
         padding: 2px;
      }`)
           
      const arrIonSelect = data.toArray(); // From Queryselector 
      // to Array of IonSelect
      arrIonSelect.forEach((isel) => {
         // Storing the current CSS rules used by the shadow-root
         const elemStyleSheets = 
            isel.el.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets;
         // Merging the rules
         isel.el.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = 
            [...elemStyleSheets, sheet];
      });
   });
}
```

Finally in the *html* we'll bind the style attribute to the required 'condition' :

```
<ion-select  
[style.--ion-label-display]="form.get('title')?.errors?.required ? 'initial' : 'none'"
label="Title" labelPlacement="stacked" formControlName="title">
   <ion-select-option *ngFor="let title of titles" value="{{title}}">{{title}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

I expect them to change something in the future, but for now I hope it helps, it did for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this (Ionic 7.0.10), but it [has been discussed as a feature request in the Github Repository for Ionic](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/27112). Looks like they will add the label as a Shadow DOM Part, allowing you to style it in the same way you can style the placeholder and text, as shown in [the answer by @Maxime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76118368/267892).